# Do I need to add a template_preprocess to declare I am going to use the content type fields in node--content-type.tpl.php?

Tags: entities, theming

I am trying to use custom templates for the first time, with zen. So I might miss a step.

I have created a node--something.tpl.php for a "something" content type. I have successfully tested it with a few fixed and variable values like $date and $name. But when I try `<?php print render($content['field_example']); ?>` it outputs nothing, same for `<?php print render($content['field_field_example']); ?>` and a few other combinations, and clearing caches at every move. 

I have the feeling that I miss maybe a preprocess declaration in the template. 

The theme version 7.x-5.5. 

 The resource documents I am using are:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/1728164
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7

I am a bit lost here.

Comment: What is the field's machine name? Are you sure that the field has content on the current node? You can implement ´template_preprocess_node´ and watch $vars['content']['field_example'] using dpm or other debugger.

Comment: like field_example and yes. Ok thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: Ok, I don't know if that is a rightway to do it, but <?php print render($node->field_example['und'][0]['value']); ?> is actually working.. I'm gonna use this at the moment and try again later on a sandbox about the print render content field.

Comment: This will work, but it is very wrong to do so. When you're using the node object directly your skipping all the preprocesses and processes that ran on that node (you are using the value directly and may even be exposed to XSS attacks).  BTW 'und' should be replaced by the LANGUAGE_NONE constant.